# Messenger plugin on Google Sites

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to get the messenger plugin working with google sites.
I've configured it with the tool provided, added the domains (fb1.jpg)
But when I paste the code as an embedded code I get some errors (fb2.jpg)

Can you help me with that?
Is it a limitation from Google sites?
Does it have a work around?

Thank you

[image][image]